# The missing DaggerAppComponent when using dagger2 in android

Tags: android, dagger-2

I tried to use a project for starting the android with dagger2, but I find all project have no DaggerAppComponent file. For example:

```
import iammert.com.dagger_android_injection.di.DaggerAppComponent; // The missing file

public class AndroidSampleApp extends DaggerApplication {
    protected AndroidInjector<? extends DaggerApplication> applicationInjector() {
        AppComponent appComponent = DaggerAppComponent.builder().application(this).build();
        appComponent.inject(this);
        return appComponent;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you built your project _after_ creating your `AppComponent`? `DaggerAppComponent` is one of the files that get automatically generated based on your implementation.

Comment: It can be compiled through when it has a error message report the missing file?

Comment: Remove or comment out the lines that gives you the error and build the project. Assuming you named the component `AppComponent`, `DaggerAppComponent` should have been generated and available for you to use it.